# Which is better for resonant design in terms of capacitor and inductor?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

For the values of resonant elements like  Lm (magnetizing inductance) and Cr (resonant capacitor ) is there a way to know which value is suitable with a specific Fr resonant frequency?

For example, are small values like (Lm= 50e-3, Cr= 840e-3)  normal?

I am interested in a resonance frequency in the area of 80 to 100kHz.

Comment: If those values are in henries (inductor) and farads (capacitor) then they look absolutely huge.  What frequency were you aiming for?

Comment: Assuming base units, your "small" values have a resonance frequency of about 0.8 hertz.  Was that your intention?

Comment: yes the value in henries and farad, my aims is  to get 80 to 110 kHz

Comment: and  is  there  any app, excel file  or calculated  can I use to  find suitable values

Comment: thanks for your response. I just assume the values of  Lm and  Cr and  I have also Lm. so my resonant tank will be  LLC, so I am trying to get an Excel file to make it more easier.

Answer (score 2):

From later comments, it seems you are actually looking at an LLC resonant converter of some kind.

Something like [the converters discussed in this application note from ON Semiconductors.](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9408-D.PDF)

You are even using the same designations for the inductors as used in this diagram from the application note:

[image]

That changes things a bit.

That circuit has **two** resonant frequencies.

Page 3 gives the equations for both resonant frequencies:

\$f_{r1} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{L_r C_r}}\$

\$f_{r2} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{(L_r + L_m) C_r}}\$

The calculations are pretty much the same as for a simple LC tank.  Calculating each resonance frequency is itself trivial.

The complete design and what things you need to take into consideration are an entirely different subject, and I'd suggest you take a good look at that ON Semiconductor application note.

I'm not up to advising you on that subject.  Read the application note, and ask new questions as needed for the parts you don't understand.

---

Old answer:

The resonance frequency of an inductor and capacitor circuit is given by [this equation:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#Resonance_2)

$$f = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

Where:

- \$f= \$ frequency in hertz
- \$L=\$ inductance in henries
- \$C=\$ capacitance in farads

The usual way to solve it is to pick any of the two variables and solve the equation for the third.

In your case, you have a frequency (80 to 100kHz) that you want to hit, so you would pick one of the other two and solve the equation to find the third.

For 80kHz, we can pick 100nF, and come up with about 39 microhenries for the inductor.

Yes, the values will be "small" for any reasonable frequency.  Note that I started with 100 nanofarads, and got an inductor of 39 microhenries.

There are many combinations that will give the same resonance frequency.  If I start with 1 nF and 80kHz, I get an inductance of 3.9 millihenries.

You'll want to try to use standard (commercially available) values for your parts.

- Pick an inductor or capacitor from the parts available from a supplier, then calculate the value of the missing part.
- Look up the closest commercially available value to the one you calculated
- Calculate the resonant frequency from those two parts.
- If it's close enough to suit you, you are done.  If not, pick a different starting point and try again.

Keep in mind that the parts will have a tolerance - the values will **not** have exactly the marked value.

---

To make the calculations easier, you can use a [calculator site like this one.](https://goodcalculators.com/resonant-frequency-calculator/)

There are many similar sites out there.  That's just the first one that came up when I asked google for "LC resonance calculator."

Comment: I'd like to add height is the crucial parameter when selecting the components. If you have plenty of available height, you can go with a low resistance coil and raise Q that way. So first think about the maximum height of your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Having chosen a frequency, you have determined a pair of component values in the form of an LC product.

This can obviously be realised as a small L and a large C, a large L and a small C, or anywhere in between, with an infinite range of possibilities (in practice, constrained by available components, e.g. E12 series of values for capacitors. But also constrained by the difficulty of making exceptionally large or small values of either component, like 100H or 1 nH, or the capacitance of your PCB traces).

The best choice depends on context : the purpose of the circuit and the components around it.

Notice two things :

1. the Q of the overall tuned circuit depends not only on the parasitic values of the chosen components, but also on the circuitry driving it (and loading it).
2. The power handling capabilities of different circuits.

Higher Q depends on low series resistance in the inductor (wire resistance, skin effect) and capacitor (ESR), and higher parallel resistance (leakage current in the capacitor)

High series impedance (thin wire) reduces Q, or increase damping in the tuned circuit.

But it also depends on series resistance and parallel resistance in the circuit driving it or loading it : for example, an antenna may be modelled as a medium to high impedance (a short antenna for LF is usually capacitive) driving a tuned circuit feeding an RF amplifier which may be a JFET with a high input impedance, or a common base BJT with a relatively low impedance.

The same tuned circuit would not drive each amplifier equally well.

For a given frequency, increasing inductance and reducing capacitance BOTH increase the impedances involved, increasing Q if you keep the resistances (e.g the source and load impedances around it) constant.

(But note you can tap the inductor or make it a transformer by adding a winding with only a few turns, to match between its high impedance and a low impedance amplifier).

So the best choice of L and C for any LC product is usually a compromise between the ideal tuned circuit, and impedance matching between it and surrounding circuitry. Easiest way is probably to simulate it in circuit, and either select L and C for the required performance, or choose the topology of the surrounding circuit to get the required Q.